# Why I can't use a case object as a polymorphic type

Tags: scala

The following code doesn't compile :

```
  case object O

  trait Show[A] {def show(a: A) : String}

  class OShow extends Show[O] {
    override def show(a: O): String = "ahoy"
  }
```

The compilation error is

```
Error: not found: type O
  class OShow extends Show[O] {
```

So, how to use a case object as a polymorphic type ?
                           ^

Comment: You have your answer but you could post the compilation errors. Since of of them is "Yo does not take type parameters" that would have pointed you in the right direction. Then the next error is "not found: type BBB" which is another strong hint that an object is not a type. And so on.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As @endeneu mention it, for case objects you need to use .type, also called singleton type annotation:

```
class OShow extends Show[O.type] {
  override def show(a: O.type): String = "ahoy"
}
```

Comment: Remark: `O.type` always returns `Object` no matter the object instance. It doesn't work if you want to (eg.) pass an object as a type parameter to a trait, then use a given function defined in the object.

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to instantiate an anonymous class giving it a type parameter, but your trait doesn't take one `trait Yo` should be `trait Yo[TYPE]`, second you are extending a function from `AAA` to `String` so you have to provide an apply method for it, third for case objects you need to use `.type`, also called singleton type annotation:

```
trait AAA
case object BBB extends AAA
case object CCC extends AAA

trait Yo[TYPE] extends (AAA => String)
def bb = new Yo[BBB.type] { 
  override def apply(v1: AAA): String = ???
}
```

If you wanted the apply to be dependent on the type parameter you should have done something like this:

```
trait Yo[TYPE] extends (TYPE => String)

def bb = new Yo[BBB.type] {
  override def apply(v1: BBB.type): String = ???
}
```

Edit: I didn't notice you wanted to make it polymorphic, in that case just remove the type parameter from the trait, you are not using it anyway:

```
trait AAA
case object BBB extends AAA
case object CCC extends AAA

trait Yo extends (AAA => String)

def bb = new Yo {
  override def apply(v1: AAA): String = ???
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you wanted to achieve but maybe this is what you are looking for.

```
trait AAA
case class BBB(x: Int) extends AAA
case class CCC(x: String) extends AAA

trait Yo[T <: AAA] extends (T => String)

def bb = new Yo[BBB] { def apply(v1: BBB) = "BBB: " + v1.x}
def cc = new Yo[CCC] { def apply(v1: CCC) = "CCC: " + v1.x}


println(bb(BBB(5)), cc(CCC("foo"))) //(BBB: 5,CCC: foo)
```