# Define a type that allows a specified subset of case objects?

Tags: scala

I'm using case objects to define an enumeration thusly:

```
sealed trait Fruit
case object Apple extends Fruit
case object Orange extends Fruit
case object Banana extends Fruit
```

This is in-line with [this official example](https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/scala-book/case-objects.html) for case objects.

Is it possible to define a type that is either an `Apple` *or* an `Orange`, but never a `Banana`?

```
val appleOrOrange: Either[Apple, Orange]
```

This ^ doesn't work, because `Apple` and `Orange` themselves are not types, but singleton case objects. Is it possible to constrain this type to only accept one or the other?

Comment: Scala 3: `val x : Apple.type|Orange.type = Apple`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3508077/how-to-define-type-disjunction-union-types

Answer (score 1):

When referring to the *types* of `Apple` and `Orange` you can use `type` to access the singleton type:

```
val appleOrOrange: Either[Apple.type, Orange.type]
```

Comment: I'm not sure `type` can be referred to as a "method"

Comment: What is it then? I actually was trying to figure out where the documentation was on `type`.

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30983781/11882002) calls it a singleton type annotation

Comment: https://scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.13/03-types.html#singleton-types "A singleton type is of the form .type. "